# print string encoding wired unicode in Java

Tags: java, unicode, encoding, utf, emoji

I am trying to convert \U0001f618 to the symbol that expresses face (I think it's called emoji ?)
My code is

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;
public class Test{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    try{
     String unicode = "\\U0001f618";
     String Title = unicode;
     System.out.println(new String(unicode.getBytes(),"UTF-8"));                                                               
     String Title = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(unicode);
     System.out.println(Title);
    }catch(Exception E){System.out.println(E);}
   }
}
```

However I can not do it. This code just prints out plain text "\U0001f618"

I have a bunch of such codes that I need to convert.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The first step would be to ensure that you are using a font that supports that unicode character. If its just a standard console output, that would be unlikely.